# How do I format negative user stories?

Tags: user-story

Following the formal user story style:

> As `<user>`, I want `<goal>` so that `<benefit>`.

Our team has found difficulties in expressing things where there is a desire by the system's owners to do something which negatively affects the user.

As an arbitrary example, let's say owner wants to have the system charge customers every time they check their email.

Following the formal style of user stories, you might write this as follows:

> As a customer, I want to be charged every time I check my email so that the system owner can increase their revenue.

Obviously the customer has no desire to be charged; the story becomes jarring to read and the language is getting in the way of the facts.

How could the requirement be written differently?

Comment: Are you having a problem writing the story or creating something you don't think is ethical?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If paying money affected customers negatively, they wouldn't be using that service. Don't worry about this. Also, users don't (usually) pay money because they want to help out system owners, but because they want some service in exchange, so your example should really be like this:

> As a customer, I want to be charged every time I check my email so
>   that I can get service X in exchange.

Also, user stories are written from the perspective of all user roles, not just end  customers. Consider writing this one from the perspective of the system owner as another user role:

> As a system owner, I want customers to be charged every time they
>   check their email so that I increase my revenue.

A general advice: Focus on the positive part of the user story and don't overthink it. They should be simple. If the user story is very negative, without a way to avoid it, then the problem is with the conception of the system, and in that case it doesn't really matter what you write on your cards.

Comment: The danger with writing from the perspective of the system owner, is that *all* the stories essentially come from the owners and the value of the `user` portion of the story is diminished.

Comment: @ProgrammingHero: That's only one alternative I suggested. :)

Comment: @ProgrammingHero I think you may be hung up on semantics.  System Owner can be the owner of the system (Eg. Product Owner).  This system owner can *also* be a unique user role in the software itself.  The user story should be written against the role or user type that happens to be System Owner, where as System Owner the person is a person in the Product Owner role of a software development team, which is in reality complely different.

Comment: @Programming Here: remember that the story exists to serve _you_ - to tell _you_ why the feature is needed and who it benefits. If it benefits the company, say so in the story so the team is clear on why the feature exists. The card exists for transparency among other things. _Knowing_ you're doing something that does not benefit the user is a *good thing*.

Answer (score 12):

The `<user>` does not have to be the end user - it can easily be the business owner/system owner:

```
As a system owner
I want to charge customers
So that the business can pay my programmers
```

Comment: I don't think having the system owner as the user is correct; every story could be written from their perspective if this approach is valid.

Comment: Also, my understanding was that the story is in reaction to something the user does (checking their email) rather than something the system owner does, so having it from the perspective of the user seems more correct.

Comment: @JohnL: the story is not in reaction to anything. It's an explanation of why you are implementing the feature. However, even though it _seems_ the user may not benefit, they usually do. Even in this specific case, they benefit because when you change them the company will be profitable, which enables the company to continue to provide the service to the user.

Answer (score 5):

User stories don't exist to fulfill some sort of methodology requirement. They exist solely to clarify what a team is doing, why they are doing, and who benefits from that. If you twist the words to obscure the meaning or fit some stringent requirement for what a story is supposed to look  like, it serves no one.

So answer the question "who does this benefit" and "why are we implementing this" honestly. Your development team needs this information to do their job. Even if the story is negative from the user's point of view, that's valuable information.

That being said, what you describe sounds more like a use case scenario rather than a story. Perhaps if you reduced this down to smaller pieces it might be more clean who the owners and beneficiaries are. For example, the feature of charging for checking email has several components. At the very least there is a UI component and a back end component, and perhaps a business rule.

You might break your feature down into these stories:

As a provider of an email service,
I want to collect a fee for each read email
so that I can earn money and continue to provide and enhance the service

As a user, I want the collection of the email fee to happen automatically so that I can read my email without having to acknowledge each fee as it is collected so that my experience is more enjoyable.

As a user, I want to be able to easily review the terms of service and fee amounts so that I understand the fees that are charged so that I can feel confident that I am getting my money's worth.

As a user,
I want the collection fee for reading email to be small
so that I can afford to use this service

Comment: I like this answer -- methodologies exist to build something. When they become dogma to be blindly followed, they are not longer serving there intended purpose.

Answer (score -1):

I agree that writing it in terms of the system owner seems wrong, because the system owner doesn't initiate this story - the user does, when they check their email.  But I don't think you need to talk in terms of what the user wants, but rather what they expect to happen.

```
As a customer
When I check my email
I should be charged
So I continue to recieve Service X
```

The user would expect to be charged because you've outlined your payment plan to them.

Comment: It doesn't matter who "initiates" the story. The point of the story is for the team to understand the business value of the story. Sometimes the business value is to improve the customer experience, sometimes it is not. Be honest. It's not like the customer will see the card. The goal is to make sure the team is clear on why you are doing something. If the reality is, you're doing it to extract money from the user, say so. However, if the real goal is to stay in business so you can serve the user, say that.

Comment: If this is how you were taught to write user stories then I am sorry to inform you that you were misled.  A user story defines what a user needs or wants not what they expect to happen.  The fact that charging for email occurs is simply a given.  As a user I NEED to be charged so that I CAN check my email.  This answer is factually and unequivocally wrong and I suggest deleting it.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood then though I would suggest just adding that as your answer. **I appreciate being set right, the downvote not so much**. And I think it does matter who initiates the story because that's how I know what stories I'm dealing with right now. There's no way I can keep them all in my head at once, so to find out what happens when a user checks their email, I go to the story beginning with `As a user, when I check my email...` If I can't reliably do that then user stories are fundamentally broken. Sorry.

Comment: @JohnL: What you are describing sounds more like use case scenarios than user stories. Both formats are OK for describing software requirements, use whichever works better for you and fits into your development workflow in a better way.

Comment: @GoranJovic +1 for giving an explanation. Thanks. Seems like there's just too many bits and pieces for something that's supposed to simplify designs. It's UML all over again.

Comment: @JohnL: I think you are making it more complicated than it needs to be. Honestly answer "why are we implementing this feature" and "who benefits from this feature" and write your story from that. It's just that simple. There are no rules about who initiated an action, who owns the story, etc. The story card exists to help clarify, not to adhere to some set of predefined rules.

Comment: Goran and Bryan make excellent points.  It sounds like you are dealing with use cases because user stories don't benefit you.  These things are supposed to help your project succeed, if you feel that they are in general an overall hindrance then use cases and user stories probably are of little to no benefit to you and you shouldn't force yourself to use them.  This is a perfectly legitimate scenario when the actual business logic, complexity and user perceived value of your software are so low that user stories are either sparse or common knowledge.

Comment: @maple_shaft that's the conclusion I was coming to. My advice based on this discussion (and my experience with a recent design document where I was asked to do user stories but decided not to) is to not try to do user stories. Write out the [scenarios | use cases | whatever], in whatever format floats your boat, as long as it's consistent. If that turns out to be user stories, cool. If not, don't sweat it. [Edit: of course, you know what the implication of that is, right?]